# how to force dark theme in custom chrome tab?

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

I'm working on an Android App which supports dark theme. I use Custom Chrome Tab to display web page. Just wondering if there is any way to force dark theme in custom chrome tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below.

```
@ColorInt int colorPrimaryLight = ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivity.this, R.color.dark_color);
@ColorInt int colorPrimaryDark = ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivity.this, R.color.dark_color);

CustomTabsIntent intent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
                .setDefaultColorSchemeParams(new CustomTabColorSchemeParams.Builder()
                        .setToolbarColor(colorPrimaryLight)
                        .setNavigationBarColor(colorPrimaryLight)
                        .build())
                .setColorSchemeParams(CustomTabsIntent.COLOR_SCHEME_DARK,
                        new CustomTabColorSchemeParams.Builder()
                                .setToolbarColor(colorPrimaryDark)
                                .setNavigationBarColor(colorPrimaryDark)
                                .build())
                .build();
```

You can find the source [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/guide-ui-customization).